# 1GB memory allocated to "lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb"

Tags: ruby, mongodb, memory-leaks, parallel-processing

I'm using Twitter, Mongo, and Parallel in a loop to retrieve and store data.

Memory utilization hitting 1.5GB+

How is GC not cleaning this?

**UPDATE:** [Here is the script in question](https://gist.github.com/jfeldstein/3769902a50ebef1fb536).

```
allocated memory by location
-----------------------------------
 973409328  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:82
 359655091  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155
  34706221  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182
  31767589  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:368
  22055648  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/parallel-1.6.1/lib/parallel.rb:183
  12129637  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/addressable-2.3.8/lib/addressable/uri.rb:525
  11115133  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:172
  10609088  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/addressable-2.3.8/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb:177
   8333448  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/base.rb:152
   6041744  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb:8
   4857232  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/addressable-2.3.8/lib/addressable/uri.rb:1477
   4583920  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:241
   4524872  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/method_builder.rb:117
   4282752  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/base.rb:151
   4200641  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/monitoring/command_log_subscriber.rb:104
   3283047  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:61
   3150696  /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor.rb:125


allocated memory by gem
-----------------------------------
1084770550  ruby-2.1.5/lib
 359655091  json-1.8.3
  53016839  addressable-2.3.8
  22069048  parallel-1.6.1
  18422826  twitter-5.15.0
  10829988  mongo-2.1.1
   8908392  memoizable-0.4.2
   6041744  thread_safe-0.3.5
   4904294  faraday-0.9.2
   3839455  other
   3382080  naught-1.1.0
   2429320  bson-3.2.6
   1123917  rubygems
    320962  rollbar-2.4.0
    205097  activesupport-4.2.4
     20005  multi_json-1.11.2
```

Comment: Without code shown it is not possible to say why it leaks. It is unlikely Ruby 2.1.5 leaks itself. If the code is complicated to post on SO, I'd suggest some debugging tools like [`gc_tracer`](https://github.com/ko1/gc_tracer) written by VM and GC's author himself.

Comment: Btw. wrong use of `Timeout` module may lead to memory leaks. It is frequently ignored, timeout exception may arise anywhere even in ensure or rescue blocks, if not explicitly handled.

Comment: Yea, how ought I be using it?

Comment: @JordanFeldstein - did you try reducing the number of threads as per my answer? did it work?

Comment: @jtmarmon It did not work :^(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby memory management is both elegant and cumbersome. It stores objects (named `RVALUE`s) in so-called heaps of size of approx 16KB. On a low level, `RVALUE` is a `c`-struct, containing a union of different standard ruby object representations.

So, heaps store `RVALUE` objects, which size is not more than 40 bytes. For such objects as `String`, `Array`, `Hash` etc. this means that small objects can fit in the heap, but as soon as they reach a threshold, an extra memory outside of the Ruby heaps will be allocated.

**This extra memory is flexible; is will be freed as soon as an object became GC’ed. But the heaps themselves are not released to OS anymore.**

That said, once you are loading many *short* strings into ruby memory simultaneously, heaps amount is increasing and this memory is never returned back to ruby. This might sound weird, but try please *not **to store** strings, shorter that 23 symbols*. That insane, sorry for the proposal :)

That might help as well: http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/

Comment: Thanks for the technical details -- I never knew this about Ruby! However, I'm not sure how to implement your feedback. Would you link to examples in the source that might be responsible for storing too many strings? https://gist.github.com/jfeldstein/3769902a50ebef1fb536 It isn't obvious to me how to perform what I'm doing without storing strings...

Comment: I suspect lines like that one: https://gist.github.com/jfeldstein/3769902a50ebef1fb536#file-twitter_enrichment-rb-L157 This `map` gorges 5000 slots (heaps) at once. Try to play with it (e.g. use `500` instead of `5000`,) but, honestly, I am not sure there is a simple way to significally improve memory consumption. Maybe it’s a good time to give [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/) a try :)

Comment: BTW, the original question _“How is GC not cleaning this?”_ is more or less answered above.

Answer (score 3):

You're loading in a *ton* of data (depending on how many users you have) and then sleeping for 20 seconds *in parallel*. So basically if you have a hundred users, you're retrieving the twitter data for 100 users at once and then sleeping, doing that again and so on. This memory probably looks like it's being attributed to the timeout process because that's who's in charge of it during the 20 second sleep.

Try reducing the number of threads you're using from `keys.length` to only a few (play with the number)

Comment: I've run it in a single thread -- It still bloats. I think I'm keeping reference to the results of each mongo query, or HTTP call ... but i can't determine where

Comment: The issue might become clearer if you refactor script to be fully object-oriented. In the past, I've been better able to pinpoint issues like this by having everything encapsulated in classes and methods. http://bugroll.com/rock-solid-rake-tasks.html might be of help; it's helped me.